# How to read stock tickers into a function?

Tags: r, function, ticker

Here is the code I have right now:

```
library("quantmod")
f=function(Symbol, start, end, interval){
  Symbol2=Symbol
  getSymbols(Symbols=Symbol2, from=start, to= end)
  Symbol=data.frame(Symbol)
  
  a=length(Symbol$Symbol.Adjusted)
  b=a/interval
  c=ceiling(b)
  
  origData=matrix(`length<-`(Symbol$Symbol.Adjusted, c * interval), ncol = interval, byrow = TRUE)
  
 

  
  return(origData)
 
}
f(SPY, "2012-01-01", "2013-12-31", 10)
```

I cannot get the ticker to be read in. My output should be the data frame, but i keep getting errors saying that "SPY" does not exist.

Comment: try `f("SPY", "2012-01-01", "2013-12-31", 10)` which solves your error. But I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve with in the matrix generator function

Comment: Thank you, this git rid of the error, but the output is still not that data frame at the end.